# (J2ME Application) File not supported when downloading JAD from WAP

Tags: java-me, download, installation, wap, jad

Im using Tracfone T301G for testing and File not supported message pop up every time I attempt to download any file in WAP server even image file.

I tried around 5 more application, JPG file and PNG file. Nothing works.

Please advise what I can do for testing my application on the phone before submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some phones are very picky when it comes to file downloads and OTA installs. For these phones, a file having a .jad extension is not enough for the phone to accept it as an actually jad file. They require correct mime-types for the file extension before accepting it.

So you have to add/edit server settings, to add mime-types for the filetypes you which to be able to download/install.

Here are some examples for mime-types:

```
.jar application/java-archive
.jad text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
.mmf application/vnd.smaf
.nth application/vnd.nok-s40theme
.png image/png
.class application/java-vm
```

Comment: I should also add, when you've added mime-types, you should give the server some time before it takes effect, depending on what kind of server you're using.